# Tendermint, GRPC and C# - Stream terminated by RST_STREAM with error code: PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: c#, .net, grpc, tendermint

I need `Tendermint` in one of my projects but have never used it before so I am trying to implement a very simple example from here first: `https://docs.tendermint.com/master/tutorials/java.html` but in `C#` (`.NET 5.0`).

(Download: [Minimal Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xo8imhxdzllavpm/GrpcTendermint.zip?dl=0))

I have created a simple `GRPC` Service trying to follow the guide as closely as possible:

`Startup.cs:`

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddGrpc();
    }
    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration conf)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGrpcService<KVStoreService>();
            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");
            });
        });

        app.UseGlobalHostEnvironemnt(env); // These are for tests and are irrelevant for the problem
        app.UseGlobalConfiguration(conf);
        app.UseGlobalLogger();
        app.UseTendermint(); // This starts tendermint process
    }
}
```

Starting tendermint uses basic `Process.Start` calls. I left the `.toml` config file with defaults and yes there is a typo in documentation, `--proxy_app` flag should be typed with underscore (errors were verbose about that):

```
public static void ConfigureTendermint()
{
    var tendermint = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"Tendermint\tendermint.exe",
        Arguments = "init validator --home=Tendermint"
    });
    tendermint?.WaitForExit();

    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"Tendermint\tendermint.exe",
        Arguments = @"node --abci grpc --proxy_app tcp://127.0.0.1:5020 --home=Tendermint --log_level debug"
    });
}
```

This is the project file where `.proto` files are being processed, they are all generated successfully and work:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc" Version="2.39.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.39.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.39.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="LiteDB" Version="5.0.11" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\CommonLib.AspNet\CommonLib.AspNet\CommonLib.AspNet.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\CommonLib\CommonLib\CommonLib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Source\Protos\gogoproto\gogo.proto" GrpcServices="Server" ProtoRoot="Source/Protos" />
    <Protobuf Include="Source\Protos\tendermint\crypto\keys.proto" GrpcServices="Server" ProtoRoot="Source/Protos" />
    <Protobuf Include="Source\Protos\tendermint\crypto\proof.proto" GrpcServices="Server" ProtoRoot="Source/Protos" />
    <Protobuf Include="Source\Protos\tendermint\types\block.proto" GrpcServices="Server" ProtoRoot="Source/Protos" />
    <Protobuf Include="Source\Protos\tendermint\types\canonical.proto" GrpcServices="Server" ProtoRoot="Source/Protos" />
    <Protobuf Include="Source\Protos\tendermint\types\events.proto" GrpcServices="Server" ProtoRoot="Source/Protos" />
    <Protobuf Include="Source\Protos\tendermint\types\evidence.proto" GrpcServices="Server" ProtoRoot="Source/Protos" />
    <Protobuf Include="Source\Protos\tendermint\types\params.proto" GrpcServices="Server" ProtoRoot="Source/Protos" />
    <Protobuf Include="Source\Protos\tendermint\types\types.proto" GrpcServices="Server" ProtoRoot="Source/Protos" />
    <Protobuf Include="Source\Protos\tendermint\types\validator.proto" GrpcServices="Server" ProtoRoot="Source/Protos" />
    <Protobuf Include="Source\Protos\tendermint\version\types.proto" GrpcServices="Server" ProtoRoot="Source/Protos" />
    <Protobuf Include="Source\Protos\tendermint\abci\types.proto" GrpcServices="Server" ProtoRoot="Source/Protos" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Source\Database\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Here is the service itself, it contains the example (linked above) translated to `C#`:

```
public class KVStoreService : ABCIApplication.ABCIApplicationBase
{
    private static LiteDatabase _env;
    private static ILiteCollection<KV> _store;

    public LiteDatabase Env => _env ??= new LiteDatabase(WebUtils.Configuration?.GetConnectionString("LiteDb"));
    public ILiteCollection<KV> Store => _store ??= Env.GetCollection<KV>("kvs");

    public override Task<ResponseEcho> Echo(RequestEcho request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new ResponseEcho { Message = $"Validator is Running: {DateTime.Now:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}" });
    }

    public override Task<ResponseCheckTx> CheckTx(RequestCheckTx request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        var (code, _) = Validate(request.Tx);
        return Task.FromResult(new ResponseCheckTx { Code = code, GasWanted = 1 });
    }
    
    public override Task<ResponseBeginBlock> BeginBlock(RequestBeginBlock request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        Env.BeginTrans();
        Store.EnsureIndex(x => x.Key, true);
        return Task.FromResult(new ResponseBeginBlock());
    }
    
    public override Task<ResponseDeliverTx> DeliverTx(RequestDeliverTx request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        var (code, kv) = Validate(request.Tx);
        if (code == 0)
            Store.Insert(kv);
        return Task.FromResult(new ResponseDeliverTx { Code = code });
    }

    public override Task<ResponseCommit> Commit(RequestCommit request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        Env.Commit();
        return Task.FromResult(new ResponseCommit { Data = ByteString.CopyFrom(new byte[8]) });
    }

    public override Task<ResponseQuery> Query(RequestQuery request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        var k = request.Data.ToBase64();
        var v = Store.FindOne(x => x.Key == k)?.Value;
        var resp = new ResponseQuery();
        if (v == null)
            resp.Log = $"There is no value for \"{k}\" key";
        else 
        {
            resp.Log = "KVP:";
            resp.Key = ByteString.FromBase64(k);
            resp.Value = ByteString.FromBase64(v);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(resp);
    }

    private (uint, KV) Validate(ByteString tx) 
    {
        var kv = tx.ToStringUtf8().Split('=').Select(kv => kv.UTF8ToBase64()).ToKV();
        if (kv.Key.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() || kv.Value.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
            return (1, kv);
        
        var stored = Store.FindOne(x => x.Key == kv.Key)?.Value;
        if (stored != null && stored == kv.Value)
            return (2, kv);

        return (0, kv);
    }
}
```

Now if I create a simple client for my service and start both projects at the same time they will both work flawlessly:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        LoggerUtils.Logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, $@"Log Path: {LoggerUtils.LogPath}");
        using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:5020");
        var client = new ABCIApplication.ABCIApplicationClient(channel);

        var echo = string.Empty;
        while (echo.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
        {
            try
            {
                echo = client.Echo(new RequestEcho()).Message;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (ex is HttpRequestException or RpcException)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                LoggerUtils.Logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, "Server not Ready, retrying...");
            }
        }
        
        var beginBlock = await client.BeginBlockAsync(new RequestBeginBlock());
        var deliver = await client.DeliverTxAsync(new RequestDeliverTx { Tx = ByteString.CopyFromUtf8("tendermint=rocks") });
        var commit = await client.CommitAsync(new RequestCommit());
        var checkTx = await client.CheckTxAsync(new RequestCheckTx { Tx = ByteString.CopyFromUtf8("tendermint=rocks") });
        var query = await client.QueryAsync(new RequestQuery { Data = ByteString.CopyFromUtf8("tendermint") });

        System.Console.WriteLine($"Echo Status: {echo}");
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Begin Block Status: {(beginBlock != null ? "Success" : "Failure")}");
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Delivery Status: {deliver.Code switch { 0 => "Success", 1 => "Invalid Data", 2 => "Already Exists", _ => "Failure" }}");
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Commit Status: {(commit.Data.ToByteArray().SequenceEqual(new byte[8]) ? "Success" : "Failure")}");
        System.Console.WriteLine($"CheckTx Status: {checkTx.Code switch { 0 => "Success", 1 => "Invalid Data", 2 => "Already Exists", _ => "Failure" }}");
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Query Status: {query.Log} {query.Key.ToStringUtf8()}{(query.Key == ByteString.Empty || query.Value == ByteString.Empty ? "" : "=")}{query.Value.ToStringUtf8()}");

        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Server working:
[image]

Client working:
[image]

So far so good, however as soon as I plug `Tendermint` into the pipeline (so clients can call my app through it), for some reason, I am getting this:

```
Echo failed - module=abci-client connection=query err="rpc error: code = Internal desc = stream terminated by RST_STREAM with error code: PROTOCOL_ERROR"`
```

[image]

It happens regardless how I start the process and the error repeats. Obviously, since `Tendermint` fails to connect to the proxy app, it is not callable either:

[image]

The errors posted above are all I get with logs set to debug (including `GRPC` logs).

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "Microsoft": "Debug",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Debug",
    "Grpc": "Debug"
  }
```

Similar threads point out to the problem with metadata (like `\n` in it) but I don't know how that would be relevant to my particular problem, you can go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57728710/how-to-fix-received-rst-stream-with-error-code-2-when-using-nginx-reverse-prox) for reference.

I am pretty sure it is a case of simple misconfiguration somewhere that prevents `Tendermint` from talking to the actual app, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `--proxy_app tcp://127.0.0.1:5020` shouldn't it be `http`?

Comment: Since you were the only person who tried to help and your suggestion got me back to reviewing the protocol itself I can award you the bounty but You have to write an answer first because it is impossible to give it for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@artur's] comment got me thinking and I have finally figured it out. Actually, even before I posted this question, my first thought was that this should indeed be `http`, despite the documentation saying otherwise, but no, `http://127.0.0.1:5020` wouldn't work. So I tried to put it in `.toml` file instead, I have even tried with `https`, but also without luck. Trying with `http` didn't throw any errors, unlike in the case when address was preceeded with `tcp`, it was just hanging on `Waiting for Echo` message (similarly to when pointing to the wrong address, which was weird). I've been always, eventually reverting to the `tcp` version. The solution was simple, remove protocol altogether...

The documentation doesn't give any clues, so for completion, at least when working with `C# (.NET 5)`, there are 3 things that you HAVE TO DO to make it work, all of them are trivial but you have to figure them out by yourself first:

1. Remove protocol from your configuration when pointing to the proxy app: `tcp://127.0.0.1:<port>` should be `127.0.0.1:<port>` and YES, it will throw regardless if you have protocol specified in the `.toml` file or as a flag in the console.
2. The flag is `--proxy_app` NOT `--proxy-app`.
3. Additionally to following the tutorial, you also have to EXPLICITLY override and implement `Info()`, `Echo()` and `InitChain()`, otherwise it will throw an `Unimplemented Exception`.

[image]

Since my understanding of `Tendermint` is still scarce, the initial approach had some design issues. Here is the code for anybody facing similar problems:

https://github.com/rvnlord/TendermintAbciGrpcCSharp